# C++ templates and alias

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, alias

This will be used in a library and not like the example, the example below is made such that it just explains the question.

I have a template class `BaseType` with a template specialization.

```
template<class...> 
class BaseType; //Forward declare

template<typename T>  
BaseType<T> { /* ...implementation 1... */ };

template<typename T, typename R>  
BaseType<T,R> { /* ...implementation 2... */ };
```

I would now create an alias for the `shared_ptr<BaseType>` templates.
Doing it for one of the template versions works fine.

```
template<typename T>
using SlotType = std::shared_ptr<BaseType<T> >;

using EventArgSlot = SlotType<EventArgs>;

EventArgSlot slot1;
```

But how should I define the alias such that it also supports this:

```
using MessageIntegerSlot = SlotType<MessageArgs, int>;
MessageIntegerSlot slot2;
```

Just adding an additional alias with the same and an additional template parameter does not work:

```
template<typename T, typename R>
using SlotType = std::shared_ptr<BaseType<T,R> >;
```

Is this possible to solve in C++11/14?

Comment: Off-topic: You do not have to put a space between two `>` in template declarations/instantiations since C++11.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could take advantage of [parameter pack](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) and change the definition of `SlotType` to

```
template<typename... T>
using SlotType = std::shared_ptr<BaseType<T...> >;
```

then

```
using EventArgSlot = SlotType<EventArgs>;              // use the 1st specialization of BaseType
using MessageIntegerSlot = SlotType<MessageArgs, int>; // use the 2nd specialization of BaseType
```